# vaadin FormLayout set custom left:right component's

Tags: vaadin7

In a vaadin FormLayout i want to show multiple components(field).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly want? What have you tried?

Comment: i want to add hybrid component in FormLayout with cation to it. i used verticalLayout added multiple formlayout as a work around.

Comment: basically i want to control what i want to add on the right side of the form layout, so that i can have hybrid component.

Answer (score 1):

You can build custom Component that extends com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent (example below).
If you want to use fields binding, things get more complicated and you should probably extend com.vaadin.ui.AbstractField and override some more methods.

```
SuperCustom dateSelection = new SuperCustom("Caption on left side in FormLayout");
formLayout.addComponent(dateSelection);

class SuperCustom extends CustomComponent {

    ComboBox ordinal = new ComboBox();
    ComboBox day = new ComboBox();
    ComboBox month = new ComboBox();

    public SuperCustom(String caption) {
        setCompositionRoot(new HorizontalLayout(ordinal, day, new Label("of"), month));
        configureComponents();
        setCaption(caption);
    }

    private void configureComponents() {
        //fill comboboxes
    }

    public Date getValue() {
        //build date based on fields
        return date;
    }
}
```